# Flash: skip X number of frames back/forward onkeypress in MP3 Player

Tags: flash

The following is the MP3 player relevant to my question, you should download the FLA file and check out the source (if you don't see the Flash scripting click on the third frame of the first layer)...

http://www.bezzmedia.com/swfspot/samples/flash8/Mp3_Player_with_XML_Playlist

All I want to do is make the `progressslider` object move right X number of frames/seconds when the user presses the right arrow key or move the `progressslider` object left Y number of frames when the user presses the left arrow key.

Below I've figured out how to do the very basic part however I'm not very advanced so the song length and oddly it also seems the current position effects how many frames the slider is moved. I'm trying to get something consistent.

```
progressslider.onKeyDown = function()
{
 if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))
 {// Seek fowards X frames or X seconds.
  playingsong.start((playingsong.position/playingsong.duration)*182+5);
 }
 else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))
 {// Seek backwards X frames or X seconds.
  playingsong.start((playingsong.position/playingsong.duration)*182-5);
 }
};
```

Please do not post guess answers, if you haven't looked at the source then don't bother to answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
myClip_mc.gotoAndPlay(myClip_mc.currentFrame + 50);
```

Comment: Did not work plus I'm not seeing any reference to "myClip_mc" in the Flash scripting, Library etc?

Comment: I just used myClip_mc as an example, replace it with the movieclip instance you are wanting to change frames in.

Comment: You have two user names? I am only modding an existing Flash object, I'm not sure WHAT object I should be referencing, could you please take a quick look at the FLA source I linked to?

Comment: Down-voted for yet another drive-by spam answer without actually taking a moment to look at the linked reference code.

Comment: Your question asked how to move a clip forward/backward by a particular number of frames and I answered that question. If you wanted to know which clip to change you should have referenced that in your original question.

Comment: If you revise your answer and it works better than what I came up with after several hours I'll up-vote and accept your answer. The FLA source is readily available via the link in my question.